# Woocommerce product not appearing in category list page when created programatically

Tags: plugin-development, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, archives

I am creating a plugin that will filter the products from API to our WordPress site. I did successfully created the product and automatically publish it with category and subcategory in it.

http://prntscr.com/mdl1jb

The problem is when I view it on my category pages it won't show up. I need to manually click the update or publish button in order for the products to show up.

What would be the issue on this  here is the code below:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
                'post_title' => $items['description'],
                'post_content' => $items['detail'],
                'post_excerpt' => $items['description_2'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => "product",
            ) );

            // Set Product type
            // wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');                            
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');                         
            // Get parent category returns mixed or objects
            $category_parent = get_term_by('name', 'Lense', 'product_cat');                     
            // Get child category returns array
            $category_child = term_exists( 'Canon', 'product_cat', $category_parent->term_id);

            // Set product brand
            // wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Canon', 'product_brand');
            // wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'Canon', 'product_brand');

            // Set category for this product post
            // wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category_parent->term_id, 'product_cat', false); 
            // wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, (int)$category_child['term_id'], 'product_cat', true);

            wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array($category_parent->term_id,(int)$category_child['term_id']), 'product_cat');


            // add_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_booking_availability', $availability );

            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_booking_option', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', 0);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', 0);
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $items['lookup_code'] );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array() );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $items['default_price']);
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', 'no' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', '' );
            // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_', '' );


            // ===================== Create product image =================
            $image = $items['cover_img_url'];

            // magic sideload image returns an HTML image, not an ID
            $media = media_sideload_image($image, $post_id);

            // therefore we must find it so we can set it as featured ID
            if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'any',
                    'post_parent' => $post_id
                );

                // reference new image to set as featured
                $attachments = get_posts($args);

                if(isset($attachments) && is_array($attachments)){
                    foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                        // grab source of full size images (so no 300x150 nonsense in path)
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
                        // determine if in the $media image we created, the string of the URL exists
                        if(strpos($media, $image[0]) !== false){
                            // if so, we found our image. set it as thumbnail
                            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment->ID);
                            // only want one image
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            // ================= Create Product Gallery
            $images = $items['images'];
            if(isset($images) && is_array($images)){

                $list_id = "";

                // magic sideload image returns an HTML image, not an ID
                $media = media_sideload_image($images[1]['full_url'], $post_id);

                // therefore we must find it so we can set it as featured ID
                if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_status' => 'any',
                        'post_parent' => $post_id
                    );

                    // reference new image to set as featured
                    $attachments = get_posts($args);

                    if(isset($attachments) && is_array($attachments)){
                        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                            // grab source of full size images (so no 300x150 nonsense in path)
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
                            // determine if in the $media image we created, the string of the URL exists
                            if(strpos($media, $image[0]) !== false){
                                // if so, we found our image. set it as thumbnail
                                // set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment->ID);
                                $list_id .= $attachment->ID . ",";
                                // only want one image
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery',$list_id);
```

Archive-Product.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );


/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<div class="site-main-product">
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php /*if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) :*/ ?>
        <!-- <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1> -->
    <?php /*endif;*/ ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    /*do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );*/
    ?>

</header>
<?php
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    /*do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );*/
    ?>

    <div class="shop-page-notices">
        <div class="woocommerce-notices-shortcode woocommerce">
            <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if(is_shop()) : ?>
        <div class="shop-title">
            Best Rental Item
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="shop-title">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_categories_header_title', wp_title( '»', false ) ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
        $taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

        foreach ($taxonomy_terms as $key => $value) {
            $is_displayed = false;
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                $brands = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), $taxonomy);

                if(!empty($brands)){
                    foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
                        if($brand->term_taxonomy_id==$value->term_id){
                            $is_displayed = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if($is_displayed==true){
                $is_displayed = false;
            ?>  

            <div class="shop-archive-brand-title">
                <img src="<?php echo $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_term_meta($value->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true), 'medium'); ?>" style="height: 60px;"/>
                <div class="shop-archive-brand-title-middle-line">
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php

                woocommerce_product_loop_start();
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();

                    $brands = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), $taxonomy);

                    if(!empty($brands)){
                        foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
                                        //var_dump($value);
                            if($brand->term_taxonomy_id==$value->term_id){
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
?>
</div>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title' => $items['description'],
    'post_content' => $items['detail'],
    'post_excerpt' => $items['description_2'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );

// Set Product type
// wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');                            
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
// Get parent category returns mixed or objects
$category_parent = get_term_by('name', 'Lense', 'product_cat');
// Get child category returns array
$category_child = term_exists( 'Canon', 'product_cat', $category_parent->term_id);

// Set product brand
// wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Canon', 'product_brand');
// wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'Canon', 'product_brand');

// Set category for this product post
// wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category_parent->term_id, 'product_cat', false); 
// wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, (int)$category_child['term_id'], 'product_cat', true);

wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array($category_parent->term_id,(int)$category_child['term_id']), 'product_cat');


// add_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_booking_availability', $availability );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', "");
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );




// ===================== Create product image =================
$image = $items['cover_img_url'];

// magic sideload image returns an HTML image, not an ID
$media = media_sideload_image($image, $post_id);

// therefore we must find it so we can set it as featured ID
if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => $post_id
    );

    // reference new image to set as featured
    $attachments = get_posts($args);

    if(isset($attachments) && is_array($attachments)){
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
            // grab source of full size images (so no 300x150 nonsense in path)
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
            // determine if in the $media image we created, the string of the URL exists
            if(strpos($media, $image[0]) !== false){
                // if so, we found our image. set it as thumbnail
                set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment->ID);
                // only want one image
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


// ================= Create Product Gallery
$images = $items['images'];
if(isset($images) && is_array($images)){

    $list_id = "";

    // magic sideload image returns an HTML image, not an ID
    $media = media_sideload_image($images[1]['full_url'], $post_id);

    // therefore we must find it so we can set it as featured ID
    if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'post_parent' => $post_id
        );

        // reference new image to set as featured
        $attachments = get_posts($args);

        if(isset($attachments) && is_array($attachments)){
            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                // grab source of full size images (so no 300x150 nonsense in path)
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
                // determine if in the $media image we created, the string of the URL exists
                if(strpos($media, $image[0]) !== false){
                    // if so, we found our image. set it as thumbnail
                    // set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment->ID);
                    $list_id .= $attachment->ID . ",";
                    // only want one image
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_image_gallery',$list_id);
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: This helps because I was commenting out some of the woo-commerce meta